# How to select dynamic child element's attribute [checked] using onclick in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm creating a dropdown with multiple selection using check box,
I had used onClick in the MenuItem of the dropdown  so user can click on the MenuItem which is parent of the checkbox to check and uncheck instead of clicking exactly on checkbox, This below code works and I can get the checked status of the check box when I render it with static value.
The same is not working I try to use dynamic values like using an array refer -FilterMultipleItems component, I'm getting undefined in the handleChange method for event.target.checked,  I'm new to react, can anyone guide me, thanks.

```
class CustomButton extends React.Component {

    render() {
      const { onPress, isChecked, values} = this.props;      
      return (
        <MenuItem onClick={onPress}>
        <Checkbox
            disabled
            checked={isChecked}                        
            value={values}/>    {values}         
        </MenuItem>
      );
    }
  }

class FilterMultipleItems extends React.Component {

  state = {open: false,}

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
   this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange = name => event => {        
   console.log(name, event.target.checked) 
   //event.target.checked getting undefined
  }


render() {
const { classes, value } = this.props;
const { open } = this.state;

 // here I'm adding the dynamic values to the CustomButton Component

var filtersItems=[];
for(var i=0;i<this.props.value.filtersValues.length;i++){
    var currentItem = this.props.value.filtersValues[i];
    this.state[currentItem]= false;
    filtersItems.push( <CustomButton onPress={this.handleChange(currentItem)} values={currentItem} checked={this.state[currentItem]} key={i}>Click on me</CustomButton>)
}

return (
  <MenuList>
    {/*rendering the component here*/}
     {filtersItems}
  </MenuList>
);
}
```

}

Comment: Bit of a self-promotion, but have you considered using https://github.com/dowjones/react-dropdown-tree-select?

Comment: Also, you could take cues from what I'm doing there to handle dynamic checkboxes.

Comment: Hi @Mrchief thanks for your response, great work I checked the component you have developed, but my requirement is similar but not using the chips for the selected values as I have multiple dropdows too, but rest are same and I want Marterials UI libraray's component.

Comment: @Mrchief how to hide or not show the chips of selected values in your component ?

Comment: You can hide them with plain CSS. With a little bit of CSS, the drop-down can adapt to material design as well. I've an example here: https://dowjones.github.io/react-dropdown-tree-select/#/story/with-material-design-styles. It's built using CodeSandbox.io so you can fork it and fiddle with it as well.

Comment: @Mrchief great work I just forked and as of now hiding using CSS works for me, you saved my time a lot.

Comment: Hope you didn't fork the project (I meant forking the sandbox to play with it). You can use the component and hide chips by overriding with your CSS: `.tag { display: none; }`. Of course, you're free to fork the whole Github project but it's not necessary for just hiding the chips! Either way, I'm glad to be of help!